# Figure is not properly displayed whiile using %matplotlib notebook in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

As you can see on the image posted below, for some reason the notebook doesn't want to properly display a figure while using the interactive matplotlib interface - the %matplotlib notebook and it only prints the top left corner of the wanted plot. I've browsed the Internet, mostly this forum but I haven't found solution either, so I've got no other choice than to make a post about it.

If I switch it back to classic %matplotlib inline, I've got no issues and the figure is displayed correctly. I'd really appreciate any help you can offer, it drives me crazy because I need to properly display these interactive plots, in order to learn from other notebooks which use them. So I'm not searching for any other alternatives to using interactive figures, but I'd preferably want this particular issue to be resolved.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was rather a quick solution to my suprise. I was even thinking of pulling this question off the site, since I resolved this quite promptly, but then again you never know, someone might end up with the very same problem as I encountered before.

So anyway, changing the browser does the trick. At least in my case changing from Chrome to Firefox solved this issue of mine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your finding with the SO, happy coding :D